# :hover only one line with text-decoration: underline;

Tags: html, css

Product name becomes underlined (product name in the layout is "Stand mixer ...", the rest shouldn’t be emphasized)

```
<div id="two">
    <div class="number_circle_top">68% off</div>
    <img class="minor_pic" src="images/img2.png">
    <div></div>
    <div id="block_container_top">
        <div id="text_top"><span class="text_line">Stand mixer with extra</span></div>
        <div class="text"> handle appreciation Gift </div>
        <div class="text"> Basket my Chu ...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="price_list_top">
        <div id="price_main_top">$49.99</div>
        <div id="price_before_top">$69.99</div>
        <div id="provider_top">Amazon</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_top">
        <div id="new_top">NEW</div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

[:hover should be when mouse poiting at this card:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYboG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#two:hover .text_line {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="two">
    <div class="number_circle_top">68% off</div>
    <img class="minor_pic" src="images/img2.png">
    <div></div>
    <div id="block_container_top">
        <div id="text_top"><span class="text_line">Stand mixer with extra</span></div>
        <div class="text"> handle appreciation Gift </div>
        <div class="text"> Basket my Chu ...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="price_list_top">
        <div id="price_main_top">$49.99</div>
        <div id="price_before_top">$69.99</div>
        <div id="provider_top">Amazon</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_top">
        <div id="new_top">NEW</div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```